# Having trouble calling getline(cin, str) in a while loop

Tags: c++

I am using

```
getline(cin , inputStr); // where string = inputStr;
```

to take input from user of string type. The code was working perfectly. But now somehow, in a while-loop, it is not being called. That is, the compiler seems to skip this part.

But `cin >> str` alone works fine. Any suggestions?

---

Code from a comment:

```
int num, choice;
string inputStr="";
while(1)
{
     cout<<"1) Search \n";
     cout<<" EXIT\n";
     cout<<"Choose your choice : ";
     cin >> choice;
     switch(choice)
     {
     case 1:
         cout<<"word for search\n";
         getline(cin, str);
         cout<< str <<endl;
         return 0;
        //just checking whether this commands work or not.
     }
     else
     {
         return 0;
     }
     .......// there is 300 lines of code still there
```

Comment: is the code `confidential`..you need to show us the code you are using

Comment: I am sorry I can't.
But are there any other commands to take string as an input from a user ????

Comment: how do you know that the compiler skipped that part?

Comment: @AzkaAhmad if you cant..then sorry we cant help you

Comment: It's probably related to the termination condition of the while-loop. Could you post the relevant parts, possibly the entire program code?

Comment: Because it is meant to take input from user and stop there until user gives the input. but it does not stop.I have to take input for search purposes.

Comment: Azka: (a) you should edit your question, not add the code as a comment, and (b) you need to learn how to produce an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help you.

Comment: @jonathan Leffler Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `cin >> choice;` leaves the newline in the input stream so the `getline(cin, str);` immediately returns due to that newline.

Try adding a `cin.ignore();` after the `cin >> choice;` to consume the newline character.

Comment: It worked.....Thanks a loooooottttttttt.......!!!!